# Self-contained reference for projective embedding of moduli of polarized abelian varieties via modular forms

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry

I've been working on reading and understanding Arakelov's '71 paper and he uses the fact that the moduli space of complex abelian varieties of dimension $g$ with polarization of degree $d$ admits an embedding into some projective space $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^N$ by modular forms of weight $m >\!\!> 0$. My understanding is this is a consequence of Satake/Baily-Borel compactification but I'd like to see the details of this, as it's pretty far outside of my wheelhouse. Are there any self-contained explanations of this?

Comment: A self-contained explanation of an even stronger result is Moret-Bailly's Asterisque "Pinceaux de varietes abeliennes" ; see http://www.numdam.org/issue/AST_1985__129__1_0.pdf

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar: Do you have a more precise reference? The book has 269 pages, so some pointer is needed...